# Escaping special characters in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, replace, lucene, escaping

I am using the [elasticsearch python client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to make some queries to the elasticsearch instance that we are hosting.

I noticed that [some characters need to be escaped](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters). Specifically, these...

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

Is there a clean way to do this beyond what I've already got in mind? Surely there is a cleaner way than doing

```
term
    .replace("+", "\+")
    .replace("-", "\-")

    # ....etc
```

I was hoping there was an API call that I could use, but I can't find one in the docs. This seems like a common enough issue that it should have been solved by someone.

Does anyone know the "correct" way of doing this?

EDIT : I am still not sure if there is an API call, but I got things concise enough to where I am happy.

```
def needs_escaping(character):                                                                                                                                                                                        

    escape_chars = {                                                                                                                                                                                               
        '\\' : True, '+' : True, '-' : True, '!' : True,                                                                                                                                                           
        '(' : True, ')' : True, ':' : True, '^' : True,                                                                                                                                                            
        '[' : True, ']': True, '\"' : True, '{' : True,                                                                                                                                                            
        '}' : True, '~' : True, '*' : True, '?' : True,                                                                                                                                                            
        '|' : True, '&' : True, '/' : True                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return escape_chars.get(character, False)   


sanitized = ''
for character in query:                                                                                                                                                                                            

    if needs_escaping(character):                                                                                                                                                                                 
        sanitized += '\\%s' % character                                                                                                                                                                           
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        sanitized += character
```

Comment: Head up for future readers: Elasticsearch has other characters that need to be escaped on top of that, too: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters (This is v2.3, refer to the one that you have deployed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, those characters will need to be replaced within content you want to search in a [query_string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).  To do that (assuming you are using PyLucene), you should be able to use [`QueryParserBase.escape(String)`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape-java.lang.String-).

Barring that, you could always adapt the `QueryParserBase.escape` source code to your needs:

```java
public static String escape(String s) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    // These characters are part of the query syntax and must be escaped
    if (c == '\\' || c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '!' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == ':'
      || c == '^' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c == '\"' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '~'
      || c == '*' || c == '?' || c == '|' || c == '&' || c == '/') {
      sb.append('\\');
    }
    sb.append(c);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: The java code helped out. I'll edit to include my python answer, but this was on the right track.

Comment: When this condition is true?
```
    c == '\"'
```

Comment: @SavvaSergey while the escaping of the double quotes is not strictly necessary in this context, the escaped double quote still will be treated as a plain, single character double quote.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted this code I found [there](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/01/17/escaping-solr-query-characters-in-python/):

```
escapeRules = {'+': r'\+',
               '-': r'\-',
               '&': r'\&',
               '|': r'\|',
               '!': r'\!',
               '(': r'\(',
               ')': r'\)',
               '{': r'\{',
               '}': r'\}',
               '[': r'\[',
               ']': r'\]',
               '^': r'\^',
               '~': r'\~',
               '*': r'\*',
               '?': r'\?',
               ':': r'\:',
               '"': r'\"',
               '\\': r'\\;',
               '/': r'\/',
               '>': r' ',
               '<': r' '}

def escapedSeq(term):
    """ Yield the next string based on the
        next character (either this char
        or escaped version """
    for char in term:
        if char in escapeRules.keys():
            yield escapeRules[char]
        else:
            yield char

def escapeESArg(term):
    """ Apply escaping to the passed in query terms
        escaping special characters like : , etc"""
    term = term.replace('\\', r'\\')   # escape \ first
    return "".join([nextStr for nextStr in escapedSeq(term)])
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer the question directly, below is a cleaner python solution using `re.sub`

```
import re
KIBANA_SPECIAL = '+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \\'.split(' ')
re.sub('([{}])'.format('\\'.join(KIBANA_SPECIAL)), r'\\\1', val)
```

however a better solution is to properly parse out the bad characters that get sent to elasticsearch:

```
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
urllib.parse.quote_plus(val)
```

Comment: Please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those characters will need to be replaced within the content you want to search in a query_string query.

```
import re

def escape_elasticsearch_query(query):
    return re.sub(
        '(\+|\-|\=|&&|\|\||\>|\<|\!|\(|\)|\{|\}|\[|\]|\^|"|~|\*|\?|\:|\\\|\/)',
        "\\\\\\1",
        query,
    )
```